# Select like and unlike record pattern SQL

Tags: select, sqlite

Lets assume I got this table, that got file pathes :

```
id    file                
 1     /etc/file.txt      
 2     /etc/.delete.file.txt      
 3     /etc/secondfile.txt      
 4     /etc/four.txt      
 5     /etc/five.txt      
 6     /etc.delete.five.txt
```

I want to get all the files that are not deleted,

So if there is a file : .delete.file.txt -> I don't want to select both .delete.file.txt and also file.txt (always the prefix is .deleted)

Expected result after query :

```
id    file                
 3     /etc/secondfile.txt      
 4     /etc/four.txt
```

How can I do that? 
(Using SQLITE)

Comment: What is the prefix, `.delete` or `.delete.` or `.deleted`? And isn't the sixth example row missing a slash?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your file column is unique, you can do this:

```
SELECT
REPLACE(file, '.delete.', '') AS file
FROM your_table
GROUP BY REPLACE(file, '.delete.', '')
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

You "delete" the ".delete." and then return only the rows that don't appear multiple times.

Comment: You could allow for multiple files of the same name by using the modulus operator... "HAVING COUNT(*)%2 = 0"

Comment: You are right, that's great. Thanks for your suggestion.